# Chemistry Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, chemistry

[image]

Here's a little chemistry themed puzzle I made for a website a year or two back. You don't need to be a chemist or anything - I only took the basics in college

Hint 1 (Probably good to know)

> 5 Letter Solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> **CRICK**
>
>  After [Francis Crick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Crick), who discovered the structure of DNA and proposed the 3 letter codes seen in this puzzle!

The letters on the left are

> [Codon Amino acid abbreviations](https://www.hgmd.cf.ac.uk/docs/cd_amino.html). Taking the equivalent 1 letter abbreviations we get:
>
> R I T Y H
> T L R V S
> I A S D C
> X L Y V S
> S C R E X
> R
>
> Notice that there are 26 letters here. This could clue an alphabet.

The compounds on the right are

> Also amino acids, and are (in order):
>
> Threonine (T)
> Tyrosine (Y)
> Valine (V)
> Threonine (T)
> Isoleucine (I)

Now

> If we compare these letters to their position in the table, and take the corresponding letter based on the english alphabet, we get a choice of two letters for each amino acid:
>
> C/F
> D/R
> I/S
> C/F
> B/K

And so

> Taking C, R, I, C and K - we get the final answer 'CRICK', based on the scientist who proposed these codes in the first place!

Comment: Nicely done!! And very quick too

Comment: @PropertyBrother Thanks, great puzzle! While just posting just a link to the website isn't allowed, hopefully you can take some more of the individual puzzles and post them here as this was very enjoyable

Comment: How did you go from the chemical formulas to the names of the amino acids? Just googling the name will give you the formula but is there a good website or tool to go the other direction?

Comment: @quarague I used snipping tool to get it on its own, and then google lens (right click an image - search google for image) and it would come up with the name straight away. Very quick to do, takes about 20 seconds for each

Comment: So essentially google image search is clever enough to recognize what's on these images. Thanks.